# Page not Refreshing After Login on React JS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux

page is not refreshing after success login.
Code:

**COMPONENT**

```
function LoginPage({ login, history, ...props }) {
      const [user, setUser] = useState({ ...props.user });
      const [errors, setErrors] = useState({});
        
      function handleLogin(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        login(user).then(() => {
          localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));
          history.push("/");
        });
      }
    
      return (
        <UseForm
          user={user}
          errors={errors}
          onSave={handleLogin}
        />
      );
    }
```

**HEADER**

```
    const logOut = () => {
          logout();
        };
        const authenticatedUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
        const Header = () => {
          if (authenticatedUser !== null) {
            return (
              <nav>
                <NavLink to="/" exact>Dashboard</NavLink>
                <a onClick={logOut} href="/login">Logout</a>
              </nav>
            );
          }
          return <Redirect to={"/login"} />;
        };
        
        export default Header;
```

can you please what am I missing, as it works fine but needs to refresh page, thanks.

Comment: Can you please share how do you setup your routes? Like the `<Router />` component, what routes you have, etc.? Maybe in the meantime you can take a look at [`useHistory`](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks) hook. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I have edited the question and added Header.js, Hope to hear your thoughts, thanks

Comment: So from what you're describing, does it mean that after successful login, the app does not load the `"/"` page?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  It does redirect but with no header, when I refresh the page manually then the header is displayed.